# Bootstrap Menu not closing on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling to get a Bootstrap menu to close on mobile.

I've read most post but a lot of examples aren't really helping.

Here's my code:

```html
<head>
    <title>Night Owlets Babysitting | Milton Keynes, Bedford and Surrounding Areas</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" /  
    <meta name="description" content="Night Owlets Babysitting - Affordable - Reliable - Trustworhy Babysitting in Milton Keynes, Bedford and surrounding areas">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- jQuery-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Numans" />
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-97888100-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body id="page-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button id="academy-navbar-collapse" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><h1 style="margin-top:-9px">Night Owlets</h1></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>

                  <li><a href="#page-top" >Night Owlets</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#Testimonies">Testimonies</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#fees">Our Fees</a></li>       
                  <li><a href="#terms">Our Terms</a></li>       
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: explain a bit more. your menu working on mobile.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, the issue is the menu on mobile view isn't closing when clicked on. when it's in the burger layout it will open but never close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this javascript code:

```
    $(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response, do i just add that in <script> tags in the head?  sorry to be dumb

Comment: Yes, put it after all script tags beginning with: <script>.

Comment: put it like: <script>  $(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});</script>

Comment: thank you, i've tried this and it didn't work i'm affraid. it looks like the menu is closing then opening again.

Comment: Ok, to make your website clear, it seems that it includes the bootstrap.min.js twice. One in the heading and one before the end of body tag. You have to remove the bootstrap and jquery scripts links from the <head> tag so that they are called one time before the end of body tag.

Comment: you are a diamond!! thank you. makes perfect sense now you say :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is already the functionality in bootstrap.min.js which you load so delete the script tag:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
    $(this).collapse('hide');
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi i've tried remving this and it's still not behaving. when i click on the collapsed menu it looks like it's closing then opening again.

Comment: Remove one of the bootstrap.min scripts first as per  @M_Mulhem comment. Shouldn't need any other js for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've just copied and tested your code above and the menu works fine on mobiles too. It opens and closes.

I suggest the problem could be somewhere on the rest your code( after the closing nav tag).

Just check if any ID name is repeated after the closing nav tag. ID names on a page should be unique.

Comment: thank you you were right it was bootstrap being called twice once in the head and once at the end of the body., this was obviously closing an re-opening the button. cheers